# Postgresql - Domain for Canadian Postal Code

Tags: postgresql, postal-code

I am trying to implement a domain to check for proper postal codes for Canada. I wrote the following but i get a constraint error. Can you please tell me where i may be wrong? i would really appreciate it.

```
CREATE DOMAIN can_postal_code varchar(6) 
CONSTRAINT valid_postal_code 
CHECK (VALUE ~   '^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d$');
```

Comment: What is the postgresql version?

Comment: this is my postgresql version

Answer (score 1):

For postgresql [up to 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html) use dollar quoting:

```
CHECK (VALUE ~ 
    $regex$^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d$$regex$
);
```

Comment: what does $regex$ mean in this expression? that i want to use a regular expression??

Comment: You can use any string inside the double dollar including an empty one. It is just to differentiate from any other pair inside your string. That would happen at the end of your string where you have the end of string matching dollar.

Comment: @ueg1990, check [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) article in the docs.